# Array list keep returning me the same value in Python

Tags: python

I'm scraping a web content from facebook and append the result to a list. But when I run the program it only returning me the same output. I want every output to be display rather than the same information.

Code:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

listposts = []

for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=50):
        listposts.append(post)

        print(listposts)
```

What i get is the same result:
[image]

Comment: try to print the post you get in the loop, the problem be in getting the post

Comment: `print(listposts)` is inside the for loop - is this a bug?

Comment: When i print `post` i can get the correct output

Comment: The code should be ok, there's provably an error in the process of scraping fb, as a side note, I would not recommend scraping fb in general, they have a lot of measures against it and even if you manage to do it they'll change it in some time again so your code will keep braking continuously.

Comment: You aren't getting the same result. You're printing the list that contains _all_ posts in every loop. Since the posts are longer than the width of your screen, you only see information about the first post in the output. If you want to see the current post, only print that in the loop. Or print the list _after_ the loop. Or enable wrapping long lines in your display

Comment: Also, please don't include screenshots of text. Include it as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image. If you'd copied the contents of the output to your question, you'd see that all posts are indeed present in the list. [Why do we hate screenshots so much?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the print out of the loop

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

listposts = []

for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=50):
    listposts.append(post)
print(listposts)
```